# template class partial specialization with different non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to "partial specialize" a template class with different non-type template parameter values?
More specifically, I am trying to combine the use of *std::vector* and *std::array* into one class according to different non-type template argument, something like this:

```
template<typename T, int Size>  //if Size given, use std::array stuff
class MyArray:public std::array<T, Size> {...}

template<typename T> //if Size is not given, use std::vector stuff
class MyArray:public std::vector<T> {...}
```

But the second template will be a redefined template error. I tried using *std::enable_if*, but have no idea how to use properly it here.

Comment: Do you consider a size of 0 to be a valid size? Do you intend to have your template get derived from `std::array<T, 0>`?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You spotted the problem. No, I don't. So I want to know how to get rid of that situation?

Comment: @sz: You can add a `static_assert` inside the first class definition to make sure Size is a value you consider acceptable.

Comment: I was going in the same direction as the accepted answer -- I was thinking about specializing on `Size` of 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a sentinel value:

```
template<typename T, int Size = -1>  //if Size given, use std::array stuff
class MyArray:public std::array<T, Size> {};

template<typename T> //if Size is not given, use std::vector stuff
class MyArray<T, -1>:public std::vector<T> {};
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/XpJ254

Comment: Giving `Size` a default value of `-1` seems appropriate.

Comment: @super: Yeah, I fixed that at the same time you commented.  :)

Comment: The second parameter of `std::array` has type `std::size_t`. I suggest `int` be replaced with `std::size_t`. See the declaration of [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span).

Comment: @Evg: Agreed, after this answer was written the OP specified that 0 is not a valid number of elements for their arrays, so indeed we can use size_t and a sentinel value of 0.